# Tapping on UITableView (not on UITableViewCell)

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

In my `UIViewControler` i have `UITableView` with single selection of items.
I want to deselect selected row when user tap on "empty rows" in tableView. I can't find an action for that tapping. Is this possible? I am using Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such action by default. You can build this yourself:

```
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .red
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableBackgroundTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:))))
tableView.backgroundView = view
```

This code creates a new `UIView` instance and adds a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it. Then it sets the new `UIView` instance as the `tableView`s `backgroundView`. The `backgroundView` is behind the `tableView`s cells.
When you tap the background, `tableBackgroundTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)` will be called. Obviously you will need to add that method:

```
@objc func tableBackgroundTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("background tapped")
}
```

**Note:** The example sets the `backgroundView`s color to `.red` so it is easier to see when testing. This is not needed for the tap to work.